# ValueError: Can't convert string to float where type is object

Tags: python, pandas, csv

london_reservoir_levels.csv was imported from [here](https://data.london.gov.uk/dataset/london-reservoir-levels) and uploaded to a Jupyter notebook. I am able to make a plot for the lower_lee_group column but not for lower_thames_group. I see from df4.dtypes that the former is a float and the latter an object.

I tried to convert lower_thames to a float type but get the same error. There are 5 NA values in the table, some in each of the two relevant columns. The first plot shows correctly. The second gives:

> "no numerical data to plot"

Next line gives the type of lower_thames_group as object:

```
import pandas as pd
df4 = pd.DataFrame(pd.read_csv("london_reservoir_levels.csv"))
df4

df4.isnull().values.sum()
df4.plot(x = "year", y = "lower_lee_group")
df4.plot(x = "month", y = "lower_thames_group")
df4.dtypes
df4['lower_thames_group'] = df4['lower_thames_group'].astype(float)
```

I would expect the last line to solve the problem but instead I get:

> ValueError: could not convert string to float: '---'

Comment: It looks like it's picking up the column value as `---`, which of course cannot be converted to float.  Please show us the actual CSV data.

Comment: So what float value were you expecting to get from the string `'---'`?  Your dataset contains missing values (01-Jan-96, for example), represented as dashes.

Comment: Thank you so much. I didn't realise that was what the message meant. 
So I should label "---" as NA and move on.

Comment: Why are you wrapping `DataFrame` constructor around `read_csv` that generates a data frame and by the way contains a `dtype` argument?

Answer (score 0):

There are outliers in your csv file.
Please manually search for the "---" string in the file and delete it

Comment: Thank you. I've amended the code and it now works. I thought "---" was the general formatting of the error message. It seems obvious now that it is not.

Comment: @AmirHosein Mohammadiyan: since the OP is using Python, he can also test for "bad value" and ignore that column (vs. manually editing the file). One way is to test if [float(x)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#float) returns  `NaN`.

Answer (score 0):

You can delete "---" string by finding it manually, and it will save the error.

And you can optimize the code as ,

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df4 = pd.read_csv("london_reservoir_levels.csv")
num_missing_values = df4.isnull().sum().sum()
df4.plot(x="year", y="lower_lee_group", kind="line", title="Lower Lee Group")
plt.xlabel("Year")
plt.ylabel("Lower Lee Group Level")
plt.show()

df4.plot(x="month", y="lower_thames_group", kind="line", title="Lower Thames Group")
plt.xlabel("Month")
plt.ylabel("Lower Thames Group Level")
plt.show()
df4['lower_thames_group'] = df4['lower_thames_group'].astype(float)

print(df4.dtypes)

print(f"Total missing values: {num_missing_values}")
```